# php - why does floor round down a integer?

Tags: php

I am confused as to why:

```
echo log10(238328) / log10(62);
```

results in 3

but

```
echo floor(log10(238328) / log10(62));
```

results in 2

I know floor rounds down but I thought it was only for decimal numbers.

How can I get an answer of 3 out of the latter statment whilst still normally rounding down?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

PHP uses double-precision floating point numbers. Neither of the results of the two logarithms can be represented exactly, so the result of dividing them is not exact. The result you get is close to, but slightly less than 3. This gets rounded to 3 when being formatted by `echo`. `floor`, however returns 2.

You can avoid the inexact division by taking advantage of the fact that `log(x, b) / log(y, b)` is equivalent to `log(x, y)` (for any base `b`). This gives you the the expression `log(238328, 62)` instead, which has a floating point result of exactly 3 (the correct result since 238328 is `pow(62, 3)`).

Answer (score 9):

It's due to the way floating point numbers are polished in PHP.

See [the PHP Manual's Floating Point Numbers entry](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) for more info

A workaround is to `floor(round($value, 15));`. Doing this will ensure that your number is polished quite accurately.

Comment: ahh... that makes sense... anyone know an alternative function that means I can accuratley achieve floor(log10(238328) / log10(62));

Comment: You can't *accurately* achieve much with floating point — or this calculation in particular at all, because you'd need effectively infinite memory to store an irrational number such as log₁₀(238328) appears to be. All you can do is add a ‘fudge factor’ before rounding down to force nearly-integer values to the next integer.

Comment: `floor(round($value, $precision));`

Answer (score 6):

If you var_dump you'll see that the "3" is actually a float. Which means its probably close to 3 and rounded up. If you wanted 3, you would have to use the sister function, ceil.

Comment: The problem is... I want to round down normally. But I found this instance was a bug in my code where is should be a integer and so should not be rounded down but was anyway... :S

Comment: May I suggest you use something like ceil(x-0.9) or something like that? This way, it'd usually be rounded down, but would be rounded up when the number is close enough. Or perhaps ceil(x-0.999)?

Comment: This may well work... but its a bit bodged... is there not a way to accurately do it in php?

Answer (score 2):

You might get better results using the round() function and/or explicitly casting it to an int rather than relying on ceil().  Look here for more information: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

Comment: Explicitly casting to an integer from a floating point is essentially the same result as running `floor()` on the value.

Comment: @Kenaniah no it's not. Casting to `int` won't round down, `floor()` will. This worked for us.

Answer (score 1):

At the cost of a little performance, you could coerce it, reducing the precision to a more useful range by rounding or string formatting the number:

```
echo floor(round(log10(238328)/log10(62), 4));
echo floor(sprintf('%.4f', log10(238328)/log10(62)));

// output:
// 3
// 3
```

You should go with the minimum precision that you need.  More precision is *not* what you want.  Rounding without flooring might be more correct, the results are different depending on precision.

```
echo floor(round(log10(238328)/log10(62), 16));
echo round(log10(238328)/log10(62), 16);
// output:
// 2
// 3
```

Answer (score 1):

there three functions for doing nearly the same:

- ceil --> `ceil(0.2)==1 && ceil(0.8)==1`
- floor --> `floor(0.2)==0 && floor(0.8)==0`
- round --> `round(0.2)==0 && round(0.8)==1`